# Using geometric series and integration to simplify term

Tags: calculus

I understand the integration up to the read circle. Could anyone tell me what is going on here. I do see that it is using geometrics series but I just am not able to verify that this is true.

[image]

Comment: It is $dt$ and not $dn$ $$\int_0^x t^n dt =\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \Bigg|_0^x = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \dfrac{0^{n+1}}{n+1} =  \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: OMG, time for a break!

Comment: Haha! In the last line they are just expanding the sum... Nothing fancy.. all the cool stuff is happening in the first line itself :D

Comment: But could you also explain how they came up with the term marked in red. I understand the integration part now but I do not see how they got the term

Comment: Recall the converging geometric series formula $$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x} $$  replace $x$ by $-t$ and see what you get

Comment: Ah thank you so much! So frustrating when I do not see this straight away!

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{1+t}=\dfrac{1}{1-(-t)} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-t)^n =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n t^n $$